# Error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol with DirectX

Tags: external, lnk2019

I have been trying all day to setup a direct x window and I know it not my code that is messing up it is my compiler but i don't know how to fix this.

```
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ReleaseObjects(void)" (?ReleaseObjects@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _WinMain@16
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl InitScene(void)" (?InitScene@@YA_NXZ) referenced in function _WinMain@16
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl InitializeDirect3d11App(struct HINSTANCE__ *)" (?InitializeDirect3d11App@@YA_NPAUHINSTANCE__@@@Z) referenced in function _WinMain@16
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl DrawScene(void)" (?DrawScene@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl messageloop(void)" (?messageloop@@YAHXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl UpdateScene(void)" (?UpdateScene@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl messageloop(void)" (?messageloop@@YAHXZ)
```

Comment: Your compiler isn't "messing up", it's your code. None of those linker errors have anything to do with DirectX either. Pastebin your Main.cpp file and any other source files that contain functions referenced in the linker errors you've posted and someone might be able to help.